# DynamoDB: Using filtered expression vs creating separate table with selected data for efficiency

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am writing an API, which has a data model with a status field which is boolean.

And 90% of the calls to the API will require filter over that status = “active"

Context:

Currently, I have it as a DyanmoDB Boolean field and use a filtered expression over it but I am contending the decision over creating a separate table with the relevant identifier which acts as a hash key for the query and saving corresponding item information corresponding to "active" status, as there can be only one item with "active" status in the item for a particular hash key.

Now my questions are:

- Data integrity is a big question here since I will be updating two
  tables depending upon the request.
- Is using separate tables a good practice in Dynamo DB in this use
  case or I am using a wrong DB?
- Is the query execution over filtered expression efficient enough and
  I can use the current setup?

Scale of the API usage is medium right now but it is expected to increase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A filter expression is going to be inefficient because filter expressions are applied to results after the scan or query is processed. They could save on network bandwidth in some cases but otherwise you could just as well apply the filter in your own code with pretty much the same results and efficiency.

You other option would be to create a Global Secondary Index (GSI) with a partition key on the boolean field, which might be better if you have significantly less "active" records than "inactive". In that case a useful pattern is to create a surrogate field, say "status_active", which you set to TRUE only for active fields, and to NULL for others. Then, if you create a GSI with a partition key on the "status_active" field it will contain only the active records (NULL values do not get indexed).

The index on a surrogate field is probably the best option as long as you expect than the set of active records is sparse in the table (ie. there's less actives than inactives).

If you expect that about 50% of records would be active and 50% would be inactive then having two tables and dealing with transaction integrity on your own might be a better choice. This is especially attractive if records are only infrequently expected to transition between states. DynamoDB provides very powerful atomic counters and conditional checks that you can use to craft a solution that ensures state transitions are consistent.

If you expect that many records would be active and only a few inactive, then using a filter might actually be the best option, but keep in mind that filtered records still count towards your provisioned throughput, so again, you could simply filter them out in the application with much the same result.

In summary, the answer depends on the distribution of values in the status attribute.

Comment: Thanks. This is quite useful. But I have a doubt about _** GSI with a partition key on the "status_active" field**_. I have sparse active records in the table but I need to first hash on the Id and then find active record. So, having status_active as a partition key will not be efficient. Sorry the  question didn't mention that clearly.

Comment: @user506591 Can you please explain what the hash/range keys are for your table? I have a feeling there may be a misunderstanding about how GSI's work but I can't be sure

Comment: I have ID for the item as Hash/partition key and it's information as the projection. And the projection also contains status_active field. And to get **Active items** I get the item with that ID and apply filter on it with **status_active=true**.

Comment: You should create a GSI and use the **status_active** as the partition key of the GSI.

Comment: But then if I have an entries like:
'false ID1'
'false ID1'
'true ID1'
This will be invalid since combination of partition key and sort key should be unique. But for a particular ID multiple _status_active = false_ is possible, so status_active has to be a non-key attribute. Am I missing something?

Comment: A couple of points to note: 1) the purpose of the surrogate status_active attribute is to only be non-null when the status is active, so you'd never have a record where status_active=false 2) the partition key doesn't have to be unique for a GSI - that's different than the requirements for tables

Comment: Thanks. And sorry if it wasn't clear I meant uniqueness of combination of partition and sort key. But I just found it. The combination doesn't have to be unique either.